# Return First Row For Given Value in a Column - BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a very large table that has a column which holds custom ID of string type for each row. For each ID, there are 50 properties in that table. This is guaranteed to be unique in the table.

My main task is to get those 50 properties in the row for a given ID.
When I run a normal query like the one below, it takes 5 sec to scan only 1 million rows.

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE id='123'
```

As per my understanding, BigQuery does a parallel search for a match after partitioning the rows into different clusters. And I believe for a given ID value it will check all the rows in all different clusters. So that even if a match is found in one partition, the others clusters will continue to get other matches.

But as the values in the ID column are unique here, can we somehow "break" the jobs running on other clusters as soon a match is found in a cluster and return the row.

I hope this will speed up the query run time.
Also, in the future, this table will grow to really large so if this can be done it will really be helpful for my purpose.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recently introduced [`Clustered Tables`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables)
This will allow you to bring down cost and improve performance

Please note: currently clustering is supported for partitioned tables only - but support for [`clustering non-partitioned tables`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables#features_under_development) is under development

If you table is partitioned you can just cluster it by id  - and you are done
If not  - you can introduce 'fake' date field and partition by it so clustering will be available for that table

Meantime, if you just interested in one row for given id - try below

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='123' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail for the idea. Will dig into it. Unfortunately,  `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='123' LIMIT 1`  doesn't make any improvement in this case.

Comment: Yes. Using clustered table reduced the query time to ~2 sec and data processed to merely few bytes whereas earlier it was 230MB. And I believe it should give almost same performance even when table size grows.